# I'd like to upgrade from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04.2 LTS, Can i do so without losing files?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 13.10

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.10, I would like to upgrade to 14.04.2, Can i do so without losing all of my files ? I have downloaded the 14.04.2 image using the torrent file on it's website

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading via Ubuntu update utility or Ubuntu software center is recommended if you really want to. Those iso images are used for new installation only and you may lose files which are on Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 without losing any data on my partition. You can save your data on another partition for being cool.

I've step my upgrade like this:

1. Connect to root (`sudo su`). After, edit the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` line `prompt=lts` to `prompt=normal` (with `vim` or another editor)
2. After saving the modification, just type `do-release-upgrade`

With this step, my upgrade just work fine and all data still here. Cannot say it's ok for another method, but pretty sure it's okay.